# Symfony projects: How to manage changes on bundles/libraries

Tags: php, git, symfony, composer-php

I have a Symfony project which uses a library also done by me. The thing is this library I made it for this project but with the intention to reuse it in the future, so its in a separate git repository and included in the composer.json.

The problem is that to make changes on this library many times I found my self changing the library in the vendor directory of the Symfony project to test it and then copy pasting to commit and push on the library repository.

Is there any way to avoid this and being able to change directly the changes in the vendor and committing to the original repo?

I know this is not a best practice by any standard but is really for a very small and personal project.

Comment: Looks like a use case for [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Comment: but I'd like to use the composer autoload feature, plus submodules are not as easy as a composer install in terms of deployment procedure

Answer (score 0):

**Change Fbeen for your own vendorname!**

create a folder in your symfony project dir with just any name e.g. `library`.

inside that folder create a directory `src`.

in the `src` directory create your new class(es) e.g.

```
# library/src/MyLibrary.php

namespace Fbeen\MyLibrary;

class MyLibrary
{
    public function returnSomething()
    {
        return 'Hi Folks';
    }
}
```

open your /web/app_dev.php file and add the second line:

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'; // AFTER THIS LINE
require __DIR__.'/../library/src/MyLibrary.php'; // ADD THIS
```

now you will be able to use the library in your application eg from your controller:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $lib = new \Fbeen\MyLibrary\MyLibrary();

        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
            'something' => $lib->returnSomething(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

now add a new composer.json file in the `library` directory:

```
# library/composer.json (remove this line)
{
    "name" : "fbeen/mylibrary",
    "description" : "This bundle is just a test",
    "type" : "library",
    "authors" : [{
        "name" : "Frank Beentjes",
        "email" : "xxxx@gmail.com"
    }],
    "keywords" : [
        "Test"
    ],
    "license" : [
        "MIT"
    ],
    "require" : {
         "php": ">=5.5.0"
    },
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-4" : {
            "Fbeen\\MyLibrary\\" : "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

On the CLI or with your GIT tool that you like init a new git repo
in the `library` directory

```
git init
git remote add https://github.com/Fbeen/MyLibrary
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push origin master
```

Go to [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/) to submit your new repository.

In your (next) project install the repo with composer:

```
composer require fbeen/MyLibrary
```

**Cheers!**